# C# for skipping some

Tags: c#

I am asking a question today because I look is skipping certain items and I think it is because its running too fast and doing too much, is there a way to fix this without manually putting a thread.sleep of like 10ms after each loop element?

Is this a known issue? any help would be appreciated! The for loop I am talking about is the 3rd one, the one after the two nested set of for's

There is about 104 items in squares after the first 2 foreach's are ran, there could be up to 1000, what is the best way to stop it skipping?

If I don't put a thread.sleep there, only the first occurence works, the rest of the items in the foreach DONT work

If I do 10ms, 3-4 miss
If I do 15ms they all work

```
List<string> squares = new List<string>();

var minX = 1;
var minY = 1;
var maxX = room.Model.MapSizeX;
var maxY = room.Model.MapSizeY;

for (var currentX = minX; currentX <= maxX; ++currentX)
{
    for (var currentY = minY; currentY <= maxY; ++currentY)
    {
        if (!room.GetGameMap().ItemCanBePlacedHere(currentX, currentY))
        {
            continue;
        }

        squares.Add(currentX + "," + currentY);
    }
}

foreach (string tileString in squares)
{
    var x = Convert.ToInt32(tileString.Split(',')[0]);
    var y = Convert.ToInt32(tileString.Split(',')[1]);

    session.SendWhisper("Attempting to place an item in X" + x + " and Y" + y);

    if (!room.GetGameMap().ItemCanBePlacedHere(x, y))
    {
        session.SendWhisper("Can't place an item in X" + x + " Y" + y);
        continue;
    }

    var newItem = new Item(new Random().Next(), room.RoomId, 1536, "", x, y, 0, 0, session.GetPlayerData().Id, 0, 0, 0, "", room);

    newItem.ExtraData = "1";
    newItem.UpdateState();

    room.SendMessage(new ObjectAddComposer(newItem, room));
    room.GetGameMap().AddToMap(newItem);

    // I only put this here because it skips
    // This slows it down a little and doesnt 
    // Make it skip 3-5 of the items 
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(15);
}
```

Comment: Which game engine does this relate to?

Comment: Hard to test what you've written. My tip is to check if the actions are running asynchronously and if they are, await for them.

Comment: Try changing the values of x and y so object don't always appear in same location.

Comment: It doesn't, it simply just puts 1 item and stops, I have checked how many items it places and its 1.